# How can I detect the cell value changed of a specific column in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have been using the react-table library to show the data to the UI. Because there are many updates for data and just some cells value is changed. I would like to avoid re-render other cells that have an unchanged value. Example, I have 3 columns:

```
Table before:

Column: A B C
        1 2 3

Table after:

Column: A B C
        1 5 3
```

I don't want to re-render A and C because their value is not changed.

The library that I use the link: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable

Comment: It would be of great help if you could share your code .

Comment: I just looking for an idea from the person who has experience with the react-table. It not related to code and I attached the library link that I used. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to re-render A and C because their value is not changed.

This is not possible with react-table(v7), it will always re-render when `data` reference is updated.

But if you are looking for solution to highlight change, then use custom `Cell` and in that checks like if `oldData[rowIndex][columnId]` is different from `newData[rowIndex][columnId]` can be helpful to visulaize diffing.